# Plate rolling - Hot or Cold rolled plate stainless steel

Tags: steel

What is preferred material for plate rolling (roll bending) when talking about stainless steel - hot rolled stainless steel plate or cold rolled stainless steel plate.

Final product would be for example shell of pressure vessel.

I would prefer to use hot rolled stainless steel plate ( for example 6 mm thick), which will ensure that less deforming of material occurs when rolling.

Comment: Wouldn't that be influence by the intended use of the rolled product? This question has been marked for closure. You may want to edit the question stating what the usage is of the product you are thinking about & why you prefer hot rolling.

Comment: First find out if you need to meet any code , like ASME. Then decide a pressure , then corrosion concerns - this will determine  alloy/stainless need. Then pick an ASTM material specification, this will define heat-treat and if rolling direction is significant.